# Can't find libmysql.dll and others connecting to MYSQL from ZeosLib in Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, libraries, zeos, libmysql

Excuse me, I would like to ask about how can I connect Delphi with MYSQL with ZeosLib. I already know the steps but I can't get it yet cause when I change the Properties in ZConnection where Connection = True, it can't. And this is the message [image]

By the way, my OS actually Linux Ubuntu and I have to use VirtualBox to work on it.
So if there's somebody know this, I'm begging you guys to help me.

Comment: Have to made sure that libmysql.dll is in your project folder or on your system path?

Comment: may you describe it clearly? I don't understand

Comment: This is elementary Windows stuff.  You need to read up on Windows `Environment variables` and in particular the `Path` environment variables.  Is is a list of folders/directories where Windows searches for .Dll files it can't find in the same directory as the application uses.

Comment: thank you, I will find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the dynamic link library that the error message is referencing.  The following link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html takes you to MySQL Download page for the latest version of MySQL 8.0.13, or go to this page if you are on a 5.X version https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Download the appropriate file 32bit or 64 bit and install it.  Find the installed libMySQL.dll and put that file in the same directory as the executable being created by Delphi

You may instead set the Zeos Connection Component's Library Location property to the directory that the dll is located in.

Comment: My lecturer say like what you say. Thank you .. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

> I have got a similar project and I used this link:
>   http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)
>   and it's working.
>
> But if you mean : set the "connection := true" in designtime, you have to use the platform assistant under the linux as well.

Comment: That link you gave me,  it's for FireDAC actually.. I use ZEOSLib, I already have some research before but when it stuck again, I got blank..